# How can Web API project access list from another project in same solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Apologies for the wordiness, I'm new to Web APIs. Allow me to provide a little background. I have a solution with three projects: Repository with SQL entity framework, Console app, and MVC Web API. My repository queries SQL, feeds that data to the console app, which outputs a list of calculations from the raw SQL data. I now want to be able to push that list to my localhost via Web API. I have the Web API pushing data to a localhost browser from a test repository with an array of test data within (this data isn't calculated, I just made a static array to see if I could pull anything), and it works just fine. But when I try to take the output list from the console app and feed it into my test repository and then push that data up the data doesn't push through. I made the output list available throughout the entire assembly so I can access the console app list from the Web API.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to restructure your projects a bit. I recommend refactoring your code so that the projects are as follows:

- Repository project: this will talk to your database and is responsible for retrieving data from your database.
- Application project: this references your repository project and performs the calculations that are currently being done in your console app.
- Console app project: this is your console app code. It references your Application project and does nothing more than request the results of the calculation from your Application project, then outputs the results to the console.
- MVC WebAPI project: this also just references your Application project. Your WebAPI web service call will request the results of the calculation from your Application project, then return it to the caller.

This will be much simpler for you to manage. Also, you can easily unit test just your Application project class methods that perform the calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was suspecting that I needed to refactor the entire solution, but I'm so new to web apps that I was unsure how to proceed. One more question - will this set up be appropriate to work with a SQL database that is updating every few seconds and to output live calculation data via the WebAPI. I'm creating this project with the end goal being a URL I can send out that will constantly show updating calculations based on the live updating SQL database. The URL will be sent to people at my work to monitor live.

Comment: Possibly. If you are trying to frequently update a user interface with live data, you have two choices: polling a web service or a WebSockets framework that holds connections to clients open and can push data as needed. Since you're already using .NET, that WebSockets framework would probably be SignalR. Polling a web service is simpler but will scale poorly. If you've only got a couple of users and this needs to be done quick and dirty, use polling for your web service. Otherwise, look at SignalR.

Comment: Appreciate the help.